# Merging vertices by distance changes geometry

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, vertices, geometry

I have a model I imported from Source Filmmaker that I want to remove double vertices from. Normally I just select all vertices and merge by distance, but this particular models changes in geometry when I merge the vertices. Here are some pictures to show what I mean:

[image: Mesh before merging vertices]

[image]

Mesh after merging vertices:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Merge by distance is not something you can do without thinking.  It does what it says, and only what it says: if any vertices are closer than the distance you specify in the operator panel, it merges all close vertices at their median point.  This can catch more vertices than you intend-- with some meshes, *even with a distance of 0.*

If you want to use merge by distance more judiciously, try selecting mesh borders that should join, then merging only those; then repeat with different mesh borders.  "Select non manifold" is a useful operation for finding mesh boundaries.